# How to automate UI of a 3rd party applications?

Tags: automate

I have a flow diagram in [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) that starts automatically with system. I want to add few blocks which will launch monitoring/diagnostic applications (CatLog, Network utilities, etc.) and will press certain buttons. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To start an application, select the "App start" block. Then choose the app you want to start and/or the activity, action that should be started when it is launched.

To  simulate a press or click on the screen, select the "Interact" or the "Interact touch" blocks. You can use the "Record interactions" of the Interact block to help click exactly where/what you want.